# how to hide Bottom Navigation Bar (Using Persistent navbar package) on new screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

I am using persistent_bottom_nav_bar package of flutter which showing 3 screens (Home screen, settings screen,profile screens). In the first screen I have a button that navigate user to another screen (mainscreen). The problem is i want to hide the navigation bar from showing in the profile screen.

Main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return   const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
     home: MainPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

The main screen

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  final PersistentTabController _controller =
      PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);


  List<Widget> _screens() {
    return [
      const HomeScreen(),
      const SettingsScreen(),
      const ProfileScreen(),
    ];
  }

  List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
    return [
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
        inactiveIcon: const Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
      PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
        inactiveIcon: const Icon(Icons.person_outline),
        activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
        inactiveColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PersistentTabView(
        context,
        navBarHeight: 60,
        padding: const NavBarPadding.only(top: 10),
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              offset: const Offset(10, 5),
              spreadRadius: 7,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _screens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
        stateManagement: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Profile Screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Profile Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: if it supports CSS you would jsut add style='display:none' to any element that you don't want to show up visually.

Answer (score 1):

In the PersistentTabView there is a function called onItemSelected

```
return Scaffold(
      body: PersistentTabView(
        context,
        navBarHeight: 60, 
        hideNavigationBar: _controller.index == 2
        padding: const NavBarPadding.only(top: 10),
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              offset: const Offset(10, 5),
              spreadRadius: 7,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _screens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
        stateManagement: true,
        onItemSelected: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _controller.index = index;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
```

The bottom nav bar will be hidden when you click on the profile icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically hide the navigation bar by using the `hideNavigationBar` argument of `PersistentTabView`. When set as true/false, the navigation bar will disappear/appear with an animation.

For your usecase, `ProfileScreen()` is index 2 so we `hideNavigationBar` where the current index is 2 (`_controller.index == 2`). See below code sample:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: PersistentTabView(
        context,
        navBarHeight: 60, 
        hideNavigationBar: _controller.index == 2
        padding: const NavBarPadding.only(top: 10),
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
              offset: const Offset(10, 5),
              spreadRadius: 7,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        controller: _controller,
        screens: _screens(),
        items: _navBarsItems(),
        navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6,
        stateManagement: true,
      ),
    );
```